# How to make a XPath query

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a xml file.

```
<ISL2015>
   <Teams>
      <ATL>
         <Dom>
            <Player>
                <Name>ATL PLAYER 1</Name>
                <MatchesPlayed>35</MatchesPlayed>
                <GoalsScored>11</GoalsScored>
            </Player>
            <Player>
                <Name>ATL PLAYER 2</Name>
                <MatchesPlayed>14</MatchesPlayed>
                <GoalsScored>09</GoalsScored>
            </Player>
```

I want to get all the values for a certain player using name of the player.
I have tried using

```
/ISL2015/Teams/ATL/Dom/Player[@Name="ATL PLAYER 1"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name is not attribute but node. So you need take it by xpath

```
/ISL2015/Teams/ATL/Dom/Player[Name="ATL PLAYER 1"]/*
```

result

```
Element='<Name>ATL PLAYER 1</Name>'
Element='<MatchesPlayed>35</MatchesPlayed>'
Element='<GoalsScored>11</GoalsScored>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind help.